# How to open a file created in Word 2007 pre-release version

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, compatibility, microsoft-word-2010

When I try opening some old Word 2007 docx files in Word 2010, I get the error message:

> This file was created in a pre-release version of Word 2007 and cannot be opened in this version.

I tried following Microsoft's [support advice](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926054), but it didn't fix the problem. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, upload the document to Google Docs and then resave it as a Word document.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Open the file with Wordpad.
- Right click over the desired document, choose *Open with…* , choose Wordpad.
- The file is opened even with photos
- Copy the whole content with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.
- Opene a new Word document in Word 2013 and paste the whole content

Comment: How dies this differ from Braids answer  from the 6th of March? (over 9 months ago). Did you want to post a comment (not an answer) to that post?

Comment: @Hennes I think this is another solution using Wordpad, not Word 2007.

Comment: Damn. Missed that. * sips coffee as suggested *

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the compatibility pack, you'd be open it with 2010. Don't know why you couldn't. But you may try this: open it with 2007, save it as an RTF, then open it with 2010.